# Simple Spark startup programmatically on mac os x

Tags: macos, scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to run something simple that used to run fairly easily, however I am encountering issues running below code (spark version: 2.4.4/2.4.3)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Sampler extends App {
  SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(
      new SparkConf()
        .setAppName(appName)
        .setMaster(master)
        .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false"))
    .getOrCreate()
}
```

I get this exception -

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "unknown"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.Jetty.formatTimestamp(Jetty.java:89)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.util.Jetty.<clinit>(Jetty.java:61)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.getVersion(Server.java:159)
    at org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.<clinit>(ContextHandler.java:128)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.getHandlers(MetricsServlet.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.$anonfun$getServletHandlers$2(MetricsSystem.scala:92)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at SparkGen$.<init>(SparkGen.scala:27)
    at SparkGen$.<clinit>(SparkGen.scala)
    at com.wd.perf.collector.metamodel.gen.Sampler$.delayedEndpoint$com$wd$perf$collector$metamodel$gen$Sampler$1(Sampler.scala:10)
    at Sampler$delayedInit$body.apply(Sampler.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at Sampler$.main(Sampler.scala:5)
    at Sampler.main(Sampler.scala)
```

Likely above happens because I have disabled spark UI, However when try without it as well I get same error.

I have solved this issue before (I encountered it a month ago and I fixed it by setting hostname on mac os x using follows):

```
sudo hostname -s localhost
```

and above snippet of disabling spark.ui and it seems to have worked but not anymore. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It was driving me crazy as well, finally I got it working by adding `logback.xml` file to `resources` directory.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

However, I still don't know the underlying cause, since Jetty is looking for a build parameter `timestamp` which doesn't exist so it fails to convert the litersl `unknown` to Long. What is the relation between this and the logging framework? No idea.

Comment: @ZhangChen if the problem has helped you, please vote up the answer